# Instant Transfer file between 2 browser clients via TCP

Tags: ajax, browser, tcp, p2p, upnp

Is it possible to create a website that makes possible this scenario:

User A logs into the website, uploads a file making a direct TCP connection to user B that it is within the same site at same time downloading the file. Without passing the file trough the server.

How to make user B to listen through a browser?

Would this violate "Same origin policy"?

Point is to use browser and no other software like P2P clients.

Is this crazy idea possible?

Comment: Wouldn't user A need to know user B's IP address?  What if user B was behind a firewall?

Comment: Webserver can easily identify both IPs. There might be turnarounds for firewalls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt webRTC covers exactly what you need.

You have two issues:

- B, if running from a web browser, cannot open a port to receive an inbound connection
- Even if B were able to do that, you will likely have to face NAT traversal issues.

The solution is to use/implement a relay server:

1. A opens an outbound HTTP/Websocket connection to the relay server
2. B opens an outbound HTTP/Websocket connection to the relay server
3. A sends data to the relay server on the outbound channel (HTTP POST for instance)
4. B reads data from the relay server on the response (to an HTTP GET for instance)

Easier said than done.... (and yes it is a feature of advanced P2P networks like JXTA, XMPP, Skype..., and yes you unfortunately need an intermediate server)

Check [ICE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245) for a specification of 'how to do NAT traversal'

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's called P2P. You don't even need Ajax.

Comment: For that you need client side software.

Comment: So you want P2P without clients. I found a vague marketing article about these guys doing that: http://solidstatenetworks.com/ . Not sure what they actually do, but give it a try.

Comment: It's not a regular P2P without client like Bitlet.org.

Comment: Either way, *someone* needs to be running software.  Either User A needs to be running a web server for User B to download a file from, or User B needs to be running a web server for User A to POST a file to.

Comment: The two clients would not neccessarily have to communicate via HTTP. But yeah, something does need to be running.

Comment: Is it possible to have that software in the server or with a client side language (js)?

Comment: I dont think so, the server must not handle the data so it cant download files for you and its not possible to access the local file system from javascript. Some browser extension would probably work better.

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking is: WebRTC.

Answer (score 0):

Others have mentioned WebRTC, but here is a live example:

http://sharefest.me